# Python Google App Engine : best way to prevent html xss?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, html5lib

The solution of just removing all HTML tags is not apprioriate for my App.

From what I have seen so far, I have found two solutions to clean HTML in Python:

1. bleach (uses html5lib). It works perfectly well on dev server but I could not have it work on production. there is an 'ImportError: No module named html5lib' when I try to import html5lib. Just as if the folder was not there. Maybe a problem with the python path of GAE.
2. lxml. It is more complicated to have it work on dev server : must install two third party binaries (libxslt and libxml2) to my local Python and then pip install lxml. Then on production, once I declared the lxml library in my app.yaml, it worked just fine.

Are there better solutions than lxml?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you not use the normal setup.py install method?

Comment: For my html5lib problem, I haven't seen the way of running the setup on the Google App Engine production server. Have I missed anything?